# HTML animation using uk-animation-fade javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

Hi I have the following in the html file: what I like to see is a block partially over the image "avatar", which disappears when I hover the mouse on it, and only the image is shown. I also have the following css files added at the top, is there anything else I should do? The animation does not work! Thanks so much please help me!

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
    <link href="assets/css/widgetkit-9e41562f.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/uikit.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/search.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/verticalDropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/social.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/theme.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js1/downloads/widgetkit-e0b74091.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="/assets/js1/downloads/ga.js"></script><script src="/assets/js1/downloads/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
```

window.setInterval(function(){var r;try{r=window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(e){}if(r){r.open("GET","/index.php?option=com_ajax&format=json",true);r.send(null)}},840000);

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23972361-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

      </script>
```

```
    <div class="tm-page">

    <div class="uk-container uk-container-center">

                <div class="tm-block ">
                <section id = "test" class="tm-top-b uk-grid" data-uk-grid-match="{target:'.uk-panel'}" data-uk-grid-margin="">
                <div class="uk-hidden-small uk-width-medium-1-1"><div class="uk-panel uk-hidden-small">
                    <div class="uk-text-center">

                <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin="" data-uk-grid-match="{target:'.tm-overlay-caption'}">
                <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-width-small-1-2 uk-width-medium-1-3 uk-width-large-1-4 uk-scrollspy-init-inview uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-fade'}">
                <div class="tm-overlay"><img src="./images/avatar.jpg" alt="avatar.jpg"><svg class="uk-hidden-small" viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m 0,0 0,171.14385 c 24.580441,15.47138 55.897012,24.75772 90,24.75772 34.10299,0 65.41956,-9.28634 90,-24.75772 L 180,0 0,0 z"></path><desc>Created with Snap</desc><defs></defs></svg><br>
                <div class="tm-overlay-caption" style="min-height: 0px;">
                <h2 class="tm-overlay-title">A results</h2>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-width-small-1-2 uk-width-medium-1-3 uk-width-large-1-4 uk-scrollspy-init-inview uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-fade', delay:100}">
                <div class="tm-overlay"><img src="./images/avatar.jpg" alt="avatar.jpg"><svg class="uk-hidden-small" viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m 0,0 0,171.14385 c 24.580441,15.47138 55.897012,24.75772 90,24.75772 34.10299,0 65.41956,-9.28634 90,-24.75772 L 180,0 0,0 z"></path><desc>Created with Snap</desc><defs></defs></svg><br>
                <div class="tm-overlay-caption" style="min-height: 0px;">
                <h2 class="tm-overlay-title">B results</h2>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-width-small-1-2 uk-hidden-medium uk-width-large-1-4 uk-scrollspy-init-inview uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-fade', delay:300}">
                <div class="tm-overlay"><img src="./images/avatar.jpg" alt="avatar.jpg"><svg class="uk-hidden-small" viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m 0,0 0,171.14385 c 24.580441,15.47138 55.897012,24.75772 90,24.75772 34.10299,0 65.41956,-9.28634 90,-24.75772 L 180,0 0,0 z"></path><desc>Created with Snap</desc><defs></defs></svg><br>
                <div class="tm-overlay"><img src="./images/avatar.jpg" alt="avatar.jpg"><svg class="uk-hidden-small" viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m 0,0 0,171.14385 c 24.580441,15.47138 55.897012,24.75772 90,24.75772 34.10299,0 65.41956,-9.28634 90,-24.75772 L 180,0 0,0 z"></path><desc>Created with Snap</desc><defs></defs></svg><br>
                <div class="tm-overlay-caption" style="min-height: 0px;">
                <h2 class="tm-overlay-title">C results</h2>

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </section>
                </div>
                </div>

                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your example is a bit messy, and you didn't mention that you are using uikit. Try to add the `uk-animation-hover` class (see https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/animation.html#animation-hover)

Comment: Thanks for your response yes it is added in the css class:


/* Show on hover */
.uk-visible-hover:hover .uk-hidden,
.uk-visible-hover:hover .uk-invisible {
  display: block !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.uk-visible-hover-inline:hover .uk-hidden,
.uk-visible-hover-inline:hover .uk-invisible {

Comment: I am actually new to this, everyone says it's an easy task but to me it sounds really complicated. Could you please tell me what components is needed to have an animation with hover reaction? Does it have to do anything with Java installed on the machine?

Comment: No it doens't have nothing related to Java. You need to pass this class to the element who you need to hover, or you can use JQuery to do the animations